# Jenkins and cFix unit testing (C++)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

Has anyone used cFix (Visual Assert) along with Jenkins CI?
How to set it up? How can i execute C++ Project Tests (Testt Framework cFix{isualAssert) via Jenkins?

Any pointers!
Thanks

Comment: Does cFix have an xml output option?

Comment: Im afraid there is not!
But i can format the output text to xml ...  
Is there some specifi format/schema recognized by jenkins ?
What to do after i have converted the cFix output to XML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a small program to convert cFix output to XML. I used the simplest Junit XML format recognized by jenkins for my program output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite>
   <testcase name="TestIsOpen" classname="A.B">
      <error type="error">Details</error>
   </testcase>
   <testcase name="TestAcceptDialPassed" classname="A.C">
   </testcase>  
   <testcase name="TestAcceptDialSkipped" classname="A.C">
      <skipped>wrong version</skipped>
   </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for posting it back. I'm sure it will help someone else :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can convert your output to the JUnit XML output format, Jenkins should be able to read it for you. You can find the JUnit format all over Google, and if needed, you can see the stylesheet on the website below.

We were using Cunit, which has XML output, but not a standard that Jenkins understands, and so I did was follow this [website](http://www.van-porten.de/2009/05/cunit-tests-in-hudson/). That stylesheet should be able to help you understand the JUNit format too.