# Objective-C code analyses plugin at hudson

Tags: objective-c, jenkins, hudson-plugins

I use the [clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) to check my code. 
At jenkins i used this [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clang+Scan-Build+Plugin) to execute the static analysis tool and generate a report.
Now i have to switch to hudson but there is no "clang plugin"...

Does somebody know a alternative plugin or a workaround to display the result at hudson?

Comment: Why are you switching from Jenkins to Hudson?

Comment: Oracle move hudson to the eclipse foundation http://hudson-ci.org/docs/news.html#eclipse and we are a supporter of eclispe so we "can not" use jenkins. Also the new licence of hudson under the eclispe foundation include all plugins of hudson. If you use jenkins you have to check each plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Does clang have xml output support? If so, you could convert your xml output to cppcheck format using an xsl style sheet.

The following link uses the same concept, except in his case it was unit tests and so he used JUnit format.

[Jenkins and cFix unit testing (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043382/jenkins-and-cfix-unit-testing-c/6059270#6059270)