# How can I show Expresso and node-jscoverage output in Hudson?

Tags: node.js, hudson, jenkins

We use Hudson (well, Jenkins now) for CI. I have just started a project based on Node.js, and am investigating Expresso and Gently (testing and mocking). I really like the fact that Expresso works with node-jscoverage to generate code coverage reports.

Has anybody started a project to display Expresso and node-jscoverage reports (or JScoveage) in Hudson? Failing that, is there some documantation on what kind of output Hudson is expecting, short of inventing an entire new plugin?

In summary, I'm looking for two types of output here. Test results (like junit) and coverage reports (like Cobertura).

Comment: I've found similar questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922867/junit-xml-format-specification-that-hudson-supports), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442556/spec-for-junit-xml-output).

Comment: this is rough.  I've spent the last few hours trying to integrate expresso with Jenkins ..... fail.  Adding a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Do Expresso and node-jscoverage produce xml output?
If so,

[Jenkins and cFix unit testing (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043382/jenkins-and-cfix-unit-testing-c/6059270#6059270)

Following the above, you could convert your xml output to formats that junit understand (for tests, using an XSLT), and convert your coverage xml output into cobertura format (again, using XSLT).

See this also:
http://www.van-porten.de/2009/05/cunit-tests-in-hudson/

for a sample XSLT.

Comment: currently, its all text output, with some color codes thrown in. I path would need to be created to generate this kind of output. I was hoping some one else had started it.

Comment: oops, "I path" should read "a patch", but I can't edit my comments.

Comment: I forked expresso, and am writing a patch. I'll update this question when I finalize the changes.

Comment: expresso has a JSON exporting option.

Comment: The "--json" flag ONLY refers to code-coverage-reports.  it does NOT output test results...

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [xUnit plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin). On their wiki page it says that it can handle txt and csv files using custom style sheets. In theory this should work for your test reports t least. I have never tried that though.

As for coverage I am not aware of any plugins that can deal with arbitrary coverage tools.

If the HTML reports the tools produce are usable you could use the [HTML Publisher plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) to link those reports in your job, and make them accessible from Jenkins. Not as nice an integration as a test tool plugin can provide, but depending on your expectations it might be enough.

Otherwise you will probably be forced to write a custom plugins. You could also try a request on the Jenkins Mailing List, maybe someone is working on such a plugin already.

Comment: Yeah.  I've looked at xUnit.  Any idea how to write that stylesheet?  I haven't found any good docs yet ...

Comment: There is an stylesheet linked on the Wiki page under http://github.com/versionone/webui-plugin, you might be able to work off that.

Comment: I'm voting this answer +1 for the ref to HTML Publisher..... that's a pretty cool piece of kit.  I'm going to play with that a bit and see what it can do.